# Setting a hotkey for connecting and disconnecting a network connection in KDE environment

Tags: networking, command-line, shortcut-keys, kde, c++

Is there a way to set a hotkey for toggling connection through a network cable:

[image]

---

Also if I have a command in command-line that can do this or a piece of C++ code that does this I can set a hotkey for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Control of the NetworkManger**

The NetworkManger can be controlled from the commandline:

man nmcli:

```
NAME
       nmcli – command‐line tool for controlling NetworkManager

SYNOPSIS
       nmcli  [ OPTIONS ] OBJECT { COMMAND | help }
...
```

The man page on the net: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/nmcli.1.html

With the dbus:

- [Configuration of the Network Manager via DBus: how to set the ad hoc mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185784/configuration-of-the-network-manager-via-dbus-how-to-set-the-ad-hoc-mode)
- http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.fi/2012/09/dbus-tutorial-fun-with-network-manager.html

Example - working at here:

Disconnecting from the current network connection and staying disconnected:

```
qdbus --system --literal  org.freedesktop.NetworkManager /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0 org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Disconnect
```

Connecting the network with th UUID:

1) Reading the UUID:

```
nmcli -p c
```

At here the UUID is 81540c01-2377-4d79-9763-d0f3104c81f3

2) Activating the connection:

```
nmcli c up uuid 81540c01-2377-4d79-9763-d0f3104c81f3
```

**Hotkeys**

One way to add the shortcuts/hotkeys is to use the KDE menu editor.

[image]

The command can be added to the KDE menu with a shortcut to run the command.

The KDE document can be found: K-Menu > Applications > Help ...

The KDE menu editor handbook on the net: http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kde-workspace/kmenuedit/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [user26687](https://askubuntu.com/a/395316/126106) these are the commands I use for reconnecting:

```
$ nmcli -p c
$ nmcli c up uuid 6e6c6430-ffae-4dc3-aeb8-60a89fa63796
```

the first one to get uuid. If there's one connection, one use

```
nmcli c up uuid  "$(nmcli -t -f uuid c)"
```

instead.

And these are what I use to disconnect:

```
$ nmcli dev status
$ nmcli dev disconnect iface eth1
```

For me, `qdbus` is useless because of upgrading to Qt5.
To give it a toggling nature which is needed to set a single hotkey for both enabling and disabling, probably a C++ code is appropriate for combining and automating these commands (time-consuming for me). Two hotkeys amy be better for me. I use this method for setting a hotkey for a command:
https://askubuntu.com/a/393343/126106

Still I worry about `uuid` (to be volatile).

Comment: this answer is to file a solution for future and anyone who may need.